# Windows phone sdk send email with XNA game engine

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna

I am making a game for my windows phone, using Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone and it went good from there, I wrote a few classes, and added assets but I encountered a problem.

I wanted to make a bug request / idea method, but no-where could I find where to email with XNA. I searched on Google but it came up with stuff like "How to use XNA game studio" and at the bottom it said stuff like "email us" so I never found it out. Basicley I couldn't find it. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send an email out using the `EmailComposeTask` class in WP8.  But it not totally automatic, the user has to select the account to send the email with then the Email display pops up then they have to click on send button.  You can try it like this:

[How to use the email compose task for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

// do this when the page has load completely (not in the constructor)

EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();

emailComposeTask.Subject = "message subject";
emailComposeTask.Body = "message body";
emailComposeTask.To = "recipient@example.com";
emailComposeTask.Cc = "cc@example.com";
emailComposeTask.Bcc = "bcc@example.com";

emailComposeTask.Show();
```

---

However, I don't think this is what you want.  What I would do instead because it's difficult to do the email thing silently is create a webpage, that you can POST to.  You then can just open a WebClient and POST the data that you need to that website.  Then on the website's back end, just decode the POST[DATA] into a database.

Hope this helps you, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, you may want to consider just opening a web page with a form for them to fill out, rather than writing emails within your app.

If so, here is the code to open a webpage on Windows Phone from an XNA game (using http://www.google.com/ as an example.:

```
WebBrowserTask browser = new WebBrowserTask();
browser.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/", UriKind.Absolute);
browser.Show();
```